# BackButton not hiding in navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've been struggling with this issue for several hours. I have an Authentication ViewController which will push to a tabBarController if the user is logged in. This will automatically create a backButton in the ViewControllers connected to the tabBarController. i'm trying to hide this back button. Here is an image of my tabBarController and the viewControllers:

[image]

I've tried several things like:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

None of the above seem to help. Could it be something with the tabBarController? since I do not have any issues with other viewControllers which isn't connected to tabBarController.

Comment: Is your tabBarController your initial ViewController ?

Comment: thats the authentication ViewController which is embedded in a navigationController and when a button is pressed it till push segie to the tabBarController

Comment: try setHidesBackButton in viewWillAppear

Comment: Okay i've tried debugging a little. When i remove the navigationController embed in the authentication ViewController and show the tabBarController modally it works. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue was that my initial view Controller was embedded in a navigationController. i Had to hide the navigationBar in that controller in order to fix the issue. Hopes it helps someone else.